# Delete all shapes in excel worksheet except form controls

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet where a macro tied to a button draws dynamic shapes based on the user input parameters in the worksheet.

I am trying to write a new macro to clean the sheet, or in other words delete all shapes in the worksheet.

I tried using the code below, and it indeed deletes all shapes, however button form controls also get deleted in the process. Is there an easy way to only get rid of the shapes (arrows, textboxes, ellipses etc.) in the worksheet? Thanks a bunch!!!

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes()

Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Shp.Delete
Next Shp

End Sub
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To delete autoshapes and textboxes only you can use:

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes()

Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Shp.Type = msoAutoShape Or Shp.Type = msoTextBox Then Shp.Delete
Next Shp

End Sub
```

Alternatively you can work the other way around and specify the types not to delete. You can use the enumerated types but it's more readable to use the type names. The following snippet will delete everything apart from Form Controls and OLE control objects.

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes()

Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not (Shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Or Shp.Type = msoFormControl) Then Shp.Delete
Next Shp

End Sub
```

A full list of MSO Shape Types.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa432678(v=office.12).aspx

Ron de Bruin has a good collection of snippets which may be relevant to anyone else coming across this question.
http://www.rondebruin.nl/controlsobjectsworksheet.htm

Comment: unfortunately it does not work: 1. form controls gets deleted as well as the shapes when I execute your 1st code. 2. second one works better: it deletes the shapes and leaves form controls alone. however, this time "text boxes" do not get deleted. I am almost certain there was a one liner code which does the trick, but I cannot remember it.

Comment: What type of form controls do you have? I've just tested it (the second one) on ActiveX Control checkboxes and Form Control buttons and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I had just edited my comment once I saw your second. As you said, the second code does not touch form controls, which is perfect. However, it does not delete text boxes for some reason.

Comment: Edited to catch text boxes. I don't know of any cleaner way but would be good to hear of it if you turn one up.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! If you can edit your post one more time (it still says the first one avoids form controls but it does not), I will make it the accepted answer. I will send another comment to let you know if I can find that one liner code which does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to delete drawing objects.

Building on Jamie Bull's excellent advice, firstly here's the updated link to the relevant page in Ron de Bruin's website:

[Delete or Hide Objects/Controls on a worksheet](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win002.htm)

and secondly, you may find that this single line will do the trick:

```
ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete
```