# Excel vba shapes inner names/types

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete all shapes except command buttons. Or to delete just ovals, straight lines and drawn lines.

```
Sub deleteShapes()

Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes

  shp.Delete
Next shp

End Sub
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789905/8052882) Jamie Bull deletes the shapes:

`If Not (Shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Or Shp.Type = msoFormControl) Then Shp.Delete`

But how can I get my command buttons types? Or other objects types? I tried

```
Sub testShapes()
    Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    MsgBox (shp.Type)
Next shp

End Sub
```

but it gives only numbers: 9, 5, 1, 12. I don't know which number is which shape. Is there any way to get an inner name like `msoOLEControlObject` or at least to make sure number 1 is really Command button?

Comment: You could also return the name in your loop and then you would know.

Comment: Are they ActiveX or Excel Form controls? Yes, it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of types is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/msoshapetype-enumeration-office
All values are defined as constants in VBA, so you can write

```
if not shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject then
    shp.Delete
end if
```

To get more infos about what kind of control you have:

```
Dim sh As Shape
For Each sh In Activesheet.Shapes
    Debug.Print sh.Name, sh.Type

    If sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
        Debug.Print "  msoFormControl:" & sh.FormControlType
    End If

    If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
        Debug.Print "  msoOLEControlObject: " & TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object)
    End If
Next sh
```

The FormControlType are shows here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlformcontrol-enumeration-excel - all are also defined as VBA constants

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default Names for the Shapes, then for Forms buttons:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Left(shp.Name, 6) = "Button" Then
        Else
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

and if the button are activex then:

```
Sub trewq()
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Left(shp.Name, 13) = "CommandButton" Then
        Else
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp

End Sub
```

This approach is valid only if the Names are of the default type.